# Button calls entirely different function than what its supposed to

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to happen is when i click the button after typing yes, it says "OLD MAN: thats good to hear, whats your name?" but instead it calls a different function saying the else answer for the question that has not been added yet. This is probably me being very dumb, because im new and bad at html/jss but if anyone sees why this is happening and let me know it would be greatly apreciated

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">  
    <center>
    <h1 class="Title"> Text Adventure HMTL </h1>
    <h5> Please write your answer directly how it was written after the question</h5>
    <br><br>
    </center>
    <p id="currentQuestion">
    <p id="givenAnswers"></p>

    <input type="textbox" id="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here">
     <input  id="enter" type="button" onclick="wakeUp()" value="enter">
    
  </body>
</html>
```

the js:

```
var answers="Yes<br>No"
var name=""
function onload(){
document.getElementById("currentQuestion")    .innerHTML=currentQuestion=currentQuestion
document.getElementById("givenAnswers").innerHTML=answers
 

}


function wakeUp(){
 document.getElementById("currentQuestion").innerHTML=currentQuestion
 document.getElementById("givenAnswers").innerHTML=answers
   if(document.getElementById("answer").value=="No" || document.getElementById("answer").value=="no" )
  {
   
   currentQuestion="You did not wake up, the game has ended, please restart"
   
   answers=""
    document.getElementById("answer").value=""
   onload()
   document.getElementById("enter").onlclick = "dead()"
   
   
   }
   else if(document.getElementById("answer").value=="Yes" || "yes" ){
    
   currentQuestion="OLD MAN: Good morning, how are you feeling?"
   answers="Good<br>Bad<br>Else"
    document.getElementById("answer").value=""
   
   document.getElementById("enter").onlclick = howUFeel()
   }
   else{
     document.getElementById("answer").value=""
   }
}

function dead(){
  currentQuestion="You have died, please restart"
  document.getElementById("currentQuestion").innerHTML=currentQuestion
  document.getElementById("answer").value=""
  onload()
}

function howUFeel(){
 if (document.getElementById("answer").value ==  "else" || "Else" )
 {
 currentQuestion="What do you mean by else? care to elaborate?"
 answers="No"
 onload()
 
  document.getElementById("answer").value=""
 }
  else if(document.getElementById("answer").value ==  "good" || "Good" ){
    currentQuestion="OLD MAN: Im Happy to hear it, do you by chance remember your name?"
    
  }
  else{


    
  }
}
```

Here you can test it and see what it does: https://idkwthisgoingon.kitten3604.repl.co/

Comment: `document.getElementById("enter").onlclick = howUFeel()` that is wrong. You are are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the handler. And it is also a typo.

Comment: So how would I change the onclick value?

Comment: @Tman06er like that: `document.getElementById("enter").onclick = howUFeel`

Comment: @Tman06er I added a possible general implementation of the dialog mechanic to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited Answer

You are using if incorrectly:  `if(something == option1 || option2)` doesn't work like you think it does.
do:

```
if(document.getElementById('answer').value == option1 || document.getElementById('answer').value == option2)
```

in your checks.

`if(something == string1 || string2)` will always return true because a non-empty string is always considered true when converting into a boolean therefore the second condition in the if statement, which is `string2`, will be true

**EDIT**

While I already answered the question, I would like to give you a piece of advice:

Try to generalize your code as much as you can. it will make your code shorter and more readable, and it will also become helpful when adding functionality and complexity to the code.

Here is my implementation of the dialog mechanic which tries to follow this advice:

```js
/* the dialog is represented by a nested object of the following form:
const dialogTree = {
    'output': 'First Question',
    'options': {
        'option1': {
            'output': 'new question', 
            'onselect': '\\<function to be executed when answering with this option\\>',
            'options': {
                'option1.1': {'output': 'new question', 'onselect': '...', 'options': {'...': '...'}},
                'option1.2': {'output': 'new question', 'onselect': '...', 'options': {'...': '...'}},
            }
        },
        'option2': {
            'output': 'new question', 
            'onselect': '<function to be executed when answering with this option, leave empty for no special effects>', 
            'options': {
                'option2.1': {'output': 'new question', 'onselect': '...', 'options': {'...': '...'}},
                'option2.2': {'output': 'new question', 'onselect': '...', 'options': {'...': '...'}},
            }
        },
    }
};
*/
// notes:
// - onselect is for special effects so don't include it if you don't want anything to happen (outside of the dialog continuing of course)
// - don't use special characters in the 'output' value (for instance <,>), instead use their entity number (see example)
// example for a dialog tree:
const dialogTree = {
    'output': 'How are you feeling today?',
    'options': {
        'Good': {
            'output': 'That\'s great, do you have anything to say to me?', 
            'options': {
                'Not really': {'onselect': die},
                'Yes, but it\'s a secret, so come close': {
                    'output': 'Ok, I\'m close, what is it?', 
                    'options': {'&#60I can\'t think of a funny thing to write here&#62': {'onselect': die}}}
            }
        },
        'Bad': {
            'output': 'Why?', 
            'options': {
                'Because this code looks bad': {
                    'output': 'That\'s hurtful :(', 
                    'options': {
                        '*truthful': {'onselect': die}
                    }
                },
                'Because I don\'t like you': {
                    'onselect': die
                },
            }
        },
        'I don\'t want to talk': {
            'onselect': die,
        }
    }
};

let prefix = 'Old Man: '; // prefix to go before each message
let dialogPath = []; // stores array of the answers so far

// some elements:
let questionEl = document.getElementById('current-question');
let givenAnswersEl = document.getElementById('given-answers');
let dialogDivEl = document.getElementById('dialog');
let deathMsgEl = document.getElementById('death-message');

// the current dialog tree (object):
let currentDialogTree = Object.create(dialogTree);

// function to be called to update the html to match the dialog data:
function flush() {
    // setting current question:
    questionEl.innerHTML = prefix + currentDialogTree.output;
    // clearing the given answers:
    givenAnswersEl.innerHTML = '';
    let id = 0;
    // adding given answers one by one.
    for(let option in currentDialogTree.options) {
        let newOption = document.createElement('input');
        newOption.type = 'radio';
        newOption.name = 'option';
        newOption.value = option;
        newOption.id = `option-${id}`;
        givenAnswersEl.appendChild(newOption); // adding the option to the div
        let newLabel = document.createElement('label');
        newLabel.innerHTML = option;
        newLabel.for = `option-${id}`;
        givenAnswersEl.appendChild(newLabel); // adding the label to the div
        givenAnswersEl.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // adding a break to the div
        id ++;
    }
}

flush();

function getAnswer() {
    let options = givenAnswersEl.children;
    // for each of the given answers check if it is checked, and if so return it:
    for(let option of options) {
        if(option.checked) {
            return option.value;
        }
    }
    // if none found, return false:
    return false;
}

// function to be called when user submits an answer:
function submit() {
    let answer = getAnswer();
    // check if an answer was given:
    if(!answer) { return; }
    // update dialog:
    dialogPath.push(answer);
    currentDialogTree = currentDialogTree.options[answer];
    if(currentDialogTree.onselect) { 
        if(currentDialogTree.onselect()) {
            // if an onselect function has a return value then we assume that it is die(), so we return:
            return;
        }; 
    }
    flush();
}

// function to be called when recalculating the current dialog tree:
function updateCurrentTree() {
    // reset dialog tree:
    currentDialogTree = Object.create(dialogTree);
    // for each option in the dialogPath, narrow the dialogTree as if that option was chosen 
    for(let option of dialogPath) {
        currentDialogTree = currentDialogTree.options[option];
    }
}

function die() {
    // hide dialog div:
    dialogDivEl.style.display = 'none';
    // show respawn div:
    deathMsgEl.style.display = 'initial';
    return true;
}

// function to be called to reset the dialog:
function reset() {
    // hide respawn div:
    deathMsgEl.style.display = 'none';
    // show dialog div:
    dialogDivEl.style.display = 'initial';
    dialogPath.length = 0; // clearing the dialog path
    updateCurrentTree(); // updating currnet dialog tree
    flush();
}
// function for going back one step in the dialog:
function backstep() {
    if(dialogPath.length) {
        dialogPath.pop();
        updateCurrentTree();
        flush();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: cursive;
}

#given-answers {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog">
        <p id="current-question"></p>
        <div id="given-answers">
        </div>
        <button id="enter" onclick="submit()">enter</button>
        <button id="backstep" onclick="backstep()">undo</button>
    </div>
    <div id="death-message" style="display: none;">
        <p>You died! click the button to restart</p>
        <button id="restart" onclick="reset()">restart</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```